# Fetch value from net/context in Golang

Tags: http, go, header, httprequest

I am using Golang net/context package for passing on the ID's wrapped in a context object from one service to another. I am able to pass the context object successfully but to actually retrieve the value of a particular key, the context.Value(key) always returns a nil. I am not sure why, but this is what I have done so far:

```
if ctx != nil {
        fmt.Println(ctx)
        fmt.Println("Found UUID, forwarding it")

        id, ok := ctx.Value(0).(string)  // This always returns a nil and thus ok is set to false
        if ok {
            fmt.Println("id found %s", id)
            req.headers.Set("ID", id)
        }
    }
```

ctx is of the type context.Context and on printing it I get:

```
context.Background.WithValue(0, "12345")
```

I am interested in fetching the value "12345" from the context. From the Golang net/context documentation (https://blog.golang.org/context) , the Value() takes in a key of interface{} type and returns a interface{} and hence I typecast is to .(string). Could anyone help with this ?

Comment: What happens when you print ("%+v", ctx.Value(0))

Comment: I get <nil> for ctx.Value(0).  But when I print ctx I get the whole thing: context.Background.WithValue(0, "12345")

Comment: What is the type of the key '0'? go will default the type of 0 to int
so When you call "Value(0)" it will call Value(int(0)) instead of Value(whatevertype0actuallyis(0))

Comment: type key int

const (
 id key = iota
)
key is set to 0 because of iota.

Comment: see @JimB's answer, you will have to use the same type as you used to set the value to retrieve the value. The type you are currently using to retrieve the value is int.

Comment: Thank you so much Benjamin. I wrote my comment on JimB's post. That worked for me. Just curious wha type does iota have in golang.

Comment: iota just lets you create integer enums efficiently it doesn't have a type https://golang.org/ref/spec#Iota

Comment: That makes complete sense now. Thanks @Benjamin Kadish.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your context key is isn't an `int`, which is the default type the untyped constant `0` will be assigned to when passed to Value in an `interface{}`.

```
c := context.Background()

v := context.WithValue(c, int32(0), 1234)
fmt.Println(v.Value(int64(0)))  // prints <nil>
fmt.Println(v.Value(int32(0)))  // print 1234
```

You need to set and extract the value with the correct type as well. You need to define a single type that you will always use as keys. I often times define helper functions to extract the context values and do the type assertion, which in your case could also serve to normalize the key type.

Comment: Thank you so much @JimB. That is exactly the issue. When I explicitly set the type to int or int32 or int64 , I am able to retrieve it. Looks like setting it to iota doesn't explicitly typecast it to int.