# How to use "type struct" saved in context in middleware accessed in controller

Tags: go, struct

This is my first question regarding GoLang please be gentle.
I am building a test JSON API.

I have a **type struct** named **User**

```
type User struct {
    UserID              int
    Email               string
    FirstName           string
    LastName            string
    PasswordHash        string
}
```

In middleware, I verify **JWT token** is valid and if so, I load entire record of User and save it in the context so that it is available in handlers under.

So in middleware, I save User struct like this

```
    context.Set(r, "User",  *User)
    fmt.Println(*User)

    next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
```

Output of **Println** is

`{12 sallu@domain.com.au Mr. Sallu $2a$14oUg3d1rm./.B/vUyhYR9/hlHfagE4tGicNc14EWK3u }`

Then in the final handler I access this context and get User object.

```
User    := context.Get(r, "User")

fmt.Println("---User---", fmt.Sprintf(" %T ", User))
fmt.Println(User)
```

Output of **Println** is

```
---User---  models.User
{12 sallu@domain.com.au Mr. Sallu $2a$14oUg3d1rm./.B/vUyhYR9/hlHfagE4tGicNc14EWK3u }
```

The issue is that in Controller when I access **User.Email** I am getting an error

```
User.Email undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)
```

How can I fix this..?
I want to use User.Email or User.UserID.
Seems like context is doing something to it.

Please help

Comment: To start it would help not to use the same name for the Type and Variable name. E.g. keep variable as `user` (un-exported) if you are not accessing it directly from other packages.

Comment: When user entered context machinery it had type `User`. When it gets out on the other end it looses it :). You'll need to type assert it back to `User`. https://tour.golang.org/methods/15

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everywhere in your code please use different names for variable and type.

e.g. keep type `User` and variable `user`.

In your controller, type assert your `user` back to `User`.

```golang
if u, ok := user.(User); ok {
    fmt.Println(u.Email)
}
```

https://tour.golang.org/methods/15

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didnt know that we can use methods to type cast (type asset).

Comment: this works for me and user.Email gets printed in console but golint keeps showing error in editor `user.Email undefined (type auth.User has no field or method Email)` 
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`User.Email` is a little ambiguous there.  You're using the same name, `User` for both the type definition and a variable.  However, the error message you're seeing:

`User.Email undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)`

shows that the compiler is understanding `User` there to be the variable, because it thinks the type is `interface{}` -- the generic type in Go.

And the error message you're seeing is slightly different from what I get if I don't use a variable at all, but just try to access a method that doesn't exist on a type, e.g.:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    Email           string
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(User.Email)
}
```

When executed prints this error:

`User.Email undefined (type User has no method Email)`

Still, it would be best if you changed your variable name to be different from your type name, e.g.

```
u := context.Get(r, "User")
```

And then you would access `u.Email`

Given that the compiler is seeing your variable as type `interface{}` rather than type `User`, biosckon may be correct that you are missing a type assertion after you extracted from context.  See [the go blog on context](https://blog.golang.org/context), especially:

> FromContext extracts a userIP from a Context:

```
func FromContext(ctx context.Context) (net.IP, bool) {
    // ctx.Value returns nil if ctx has no value for the key;
    // the net.IP type assertion returns ok=false for nil.
    userIP, ok := ctx.Value(userIPKey).(net.IP)
    return userIP, ok
}
```

See also [this Stackoverflow question and answer on fetching values from context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37866616/fetch-value-from-net-context-in-golang), especially:

> You need to set and extract the value with the correct type as well...I often times define helper functions to extract the context values and do the type assertion

What's strange about that is the output of your print statements, which make it look like you have the right type.  But again that's a little ambiguous since you're using the same name for a variable and a type.  And -- it doesn't look like you shared all your code -- are those prints from the scope where you first set them rather than after extracting from context in a different scope?  If so, that would explain the difference.